# sed replace inside a group/match

Tags: sed

I have the following log line:

> 2017-01-01 Client:abc ID:144

I need to process it and insert it in MySQL, but sometimes the data might come wrong:

> 2017-01-01 Client:a, b .c ID:144

How can I perform a sed replace only inside the "Client:xxx" group so I can remove the unwanted characters?

Comment: Where does your "Client:xxx" group end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using backreferences and `t` command, to capture and output only wanted characters between `Client:` and `ID`:

```
$ sed -r ':a;s/(Client:[^ ,.]*)[ ,.](.* ID)/\1\2/;ta;' <<< "2017-01-01 Client:a, b .c ID:144"
2017-01-01 Client:abc ID:144
```

All characters up to and excluding next unwanted character(`[ ,.]`) are captured and output. The `t`(for test) command loops to the beginning of the script(to the `:a` label) if the substitution succeeds.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I did learn about capture groups, but didn't know how to exclude characters. I have no idea what :a; and ;ta; do but I'll look it up. However if you want to explain it and make this a more informative post for others reading it, it's appreciated.